# mutliple variables in a 'ggridges' plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, frequency, ggridges

I discovered this amazing R package `ggridges` and would like to use it for a graph, however, I am failing at executing the code, as I am probably wrongly putting my variables. I was hoping someone could guide me in obtaining the result I want.

Please see my table below in R

**Data frame**

```
g<-data.frame(structure(list(session = c("s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
"s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", 
"s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", 
"s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
"s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
"s3", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", 
"s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s4", "s5", "s5", "s5", "s6", 
"s6", "s6", "s6", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7", "s7"), interval = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L), .Label = c("120", "240", "360", "480", "600", "720", "840", 
"960", "1080", "1200", "1320", "1440"), class = "factor"), person = c("person2", 
"person1", "person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", "person1", "person2", 
"person1", "person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", 
"person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", "person1", 
"person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", "person2", 
"person1", "person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", "person1", "person1", 
"person1", "person1", "person1", "person2", "person1", "person1", "person2", 
"person1", "person2", "person1", "person1", "person2", "person1", "person2", 
"person1", "person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", 
"person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", "person1", "person2", "person2", 
"person2", "person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", 
"person2", "person1", "person2", "person1", "person1", "person2", "person2", 
"person2", "person1", "person2", "person2", "person1", "person1", "person1", 
"person1", "person1", "person1", "person1", "person1", "person1"), counts = c(12L, 
51L, 15L, 43L, 4L, 54L, 42L, 12L, 51L, 9L, 73L, 3L, 38L, 12L, 
58L, 13L, 58L, 9L, 62L, 13L, 40L, 21L, 2L, 8L, 31L, 15L, 27L, 
29L, 17L, 13L, 22L, 4L, 9L, 29L, 25L, 4L, 26L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 
18L, 3L, 19L, 2L, 36L, 38L, 12L, 29L, 8L, 15L, 10L, 20L, 14L, 
11L, 9L, 23L, 13L, 20L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 15L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 
17L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 14L, 4L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 19L, 
7L, 6L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 11L, 9L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -91L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

**Columns**

- *session*: is the grouping context of my data
- *interval*: are regular  pre-defined time-slots/stamps (here: every 120 seconds) within each session
- *person*: there are two people from whom the data was taken
- *counts*: is the number of observations made within each interval for each person in each session

**R Code**

I firstly experiment with a code for `ggridges`:

```
ggplot(
  g, 
  aes(x = `counts`, y = `session`, fill = stat(x))
  ) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(scale = 3, size = 0.3, rel_min_height = 0.01) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "counts", option = "C")
```

**Output**

This output looks very promising. Adding the following line `+ facet_grid(.~person)` would give me a graph for person 1 and 2, which is what I am looking for. It is also great to see that the colors represent the frequency of counts (darker color stand for fewer and lighter color for more counts)

[image: Output1]

**Problem description**

My main problem with the code is that no matter how I twist it and tweak it (adding `height = counts, fill= counts`), I don't see the graph because some parts of the code work and other's do not. In particular,

- *session*: should be displayed on the y-axis (works!)
- *interval*: should be displayed on the x-axis (works!)
- *counts*: should be displayed as the height of the density curve and have a different gradient color depending on the frequency of counts (***doesn't work!***)
- *person*: I want to have separate graphs for person 1 and 2 (works if I add  `+ facet_grid(.~person)`)

**Desired graph**

Although made with a pen-and-paper method and being not very elegant, this is the desired graph I am aiming at getting. The peaks on the density curves (in circles) correspond to `counts` pointed out for each session and each person in my data frame.

[image: Penandpaper]

Maybe my approach is wrong, and the package is not the one I am looking for, but if not I would appreciate if someone with a higher expertise in R could advise me on this issue.

Comment: I think you want `stat(density)` rather than `stat(x)`. If not, please can you sketch what it should look like

Comment: Your suggestion is not working with the indicated code (although I also believe that density is somehow a key word for my R code) and the graph is empty. For a better reference, as suggested, I added a desired graph that I wish to get. I hope, this clarifies the final "end product".

Comment: Found a solution yet?